# Flutter/RiverPod - is it OK to call ref.read inside a FutureProvider code?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Is it legit to include a ref.read call inside a Future Provider? As shown below...

```
final findHabitTrackingPeriodProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<FindHabitTrackingPeriodModel, GdHabit>( (ref, habit) async {
  List<GdHabitTrackingPeriod> aPeriodsFound = await ref.watch(habitServiceProvider).findTrackingPeriods();
  ref.read(currentHabitTrackingPeriodProvider.notifier).setCurrent(aPeriodsFound[0]);
  return aModel;
});
```

Comment: Build methods or create callbacks should NOT modify other providers.  This can lead to looped dependencies.  Your dependencies must be strictly a DAG.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes.

One of the core concepts for Riverpod is to listen or reference to another providers using the ref variable.

You can make all calculations by referencing one provider to another returning desired result to UI by watching just one provider variable.